# .Net: subclassing subclasses of EventSource

Tags: c#, etw, eventsource

I have a C# solution which spans many, many projects. I created a tracing class that inherits from Systme.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource, called MyCustomEventSource, which handles most of my tracing events. I want to create subclasses of this class for each project, so that I can implement events relevant to specific projects.

I am also writing an ETW consumer where I can easily listen to events from the different components of my system.

But my consumer doesn't recognize events correctly: when I listen to MyCustomEventSource, the EventName field of each event is set to the name of the method, and FormattedMessage is set to the Message attribute. Example:

```
[Event(1,
         Message = "The configuration parameter \"{0}\" was loaded with a value of {1}.",
         Level = EventLevel.Informational,
         Task = Tasks.Configuration,
         Keywords = Keywords.Diagnostics)]
    public void ConfigParameterLoaded(string name, string value)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, name, value);
    }
```

If I listen to MyCustomEventSource, and an app calls ConfigParameterLoaded, then I get an event whose name is ConfigParameterLoaded, and its FormattedMessage is "The configuration parameter "x" was loaded with a value of y."

This is fine.

But, if I create a similar method on the subclass of MyCustomEventSource and trigger events from this subclass, my EventName will always be "EventSourceMessage", and the FormattedMessage will always be null.

I figure this is probably because System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventAttribute doesn't have AttributeUsage(Inherited=true).

My question is: is there some way to get around this, and get the correct information when triggering events from a subclass?

Comment: This is a totally valid question. Why did someone vote to close this?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does't work because it is not allowed. You are only allowed to implement interface and derive from abstract class that doesn't include any events, tasks, keywords. Read the `_EventSourceUsersGuide.docx`:

> Starting with the RTM release of the EventSource NuGet package it is
>   now possible to specify event source types that are implementing an
>   interface.
>   The initial design decision (in the beta release of the NuGet package) to explicitly disallow event source class hierarchies.
>   In the new approach one can define utility event source types:
>   abstract event source classes that derive from EventSource and hold
>   all code common to a set of event sources. These abstract classes
>   **cannot define any ETW-specific elements: keywords, tasks, opcodes,
>   channels, events.** They can only provide methods to be used by derived
>   classes.